# How spring boot application knows in which environment code is running?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How spring boot application knows where code is running??

`local/dev` environment

`test` environment

`stage` environment

`prod` environment

is there a way where spring boot app automatically pulls configurations from env specific file based on current environment of running app?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't know if you don't configuration.

Please read them:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-env-variables
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty